# Better plugin to publish xml reports in jenkins

Tags: jenkins-plugins

Thanks for looking into this.

I am using JUnit JUnit results plugin, to publish the unit test results from maven(JUnit) and XML reports generated by XML runner.

But, this plugin is failing to parse the test reports(XML file) generated by XML runner.

My concerns are:
what is the best plugin to publish test results from the XML file generated by any kind of utility(JUnit/XML parser etc)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The Jenkins JUnit plugin (https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/JUnit+Plugin) should (normally) work fine:

1. What is the error that you are getting?
2. How does/do the JUnit XML file/s look like?

Regards,
  Reinhold

P.S.: There is also Jenkins xUnit plugin (https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/xUnit+Plugin), but I am not sure if that parses differently...

Comment: Thanks for prompt response.
Here's the error:
**Did not manage to validate **/*results.xml,**/surefire-reports/*.xml (may be too slow)**

Comment: Just off the top of my head: maybe your Ant file selector expression for test result files is invalid? => Which expression do you use?
Are you using pipelines or old freestyle configuration?
How do the result files and also the result folder structure look like?

Please note that for recursive folder inclusion you might need "**" instead of just "*".

Comment: Sorry, the last sentence should say double asterisk instead of a single one, but it got escaped or so.  

And please also mind the documentation for Test report XMLs like "Be sure not to include any non-report files into this pattern."